# Convert short int[] to char*

Tags: c++

How can I convert short int[] to char*?

```
short int test[4000];
char* test2;
```

I tried this:

```
test2 = (char*)test[4000]
```

Error--> PTR is not valid

Comment: Do you want to *cast the type* or *convert the values*? In other words, what should `test2` contain and what do you want to do with it?

Comment: Presumably you *are* trying to access the raw binary data, and not trying to output a string?

Comment: test is a buffer and i would write it on file but fprint requires a char*. is there better solution?

Comment: @user1611777: is it input obtained through `getc()`, `getchar()` or `fgetc()`? Or what kind of buffer is it? And what do you want to write, raw binary data or text representation of numbers in it?

Comment: No, it's obtained through MMlib functions, used for managing sound in microsoft OS

Comment: Ah, then you want to write raw sound data? Then you don't want `fprintf()` but `fwrite()`, I'll write that in an answer.

Comment: yes fwrite(), not fprintf(). Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have a buffer in form of an array, and you want to write the binary contents of it into a file. You do it like this:

```
if (fwrite(test, sizeof(test), 1, f) < 1)
{
    // handle error here (write failed)
}
```

`fwrite()` function is used to write binary data to files (and `fread()` to read). It takes a `void*` pointer, so it can work with any type (and C++ implicitly converts any other pointer/array to it).

The `sizeof(test)` determines the *exact* size of the array. If you don't want to write the whole of it (i.e. just filled part of it), you want to use `sizeof(short) * N`, where *N* is the number of filled elements.

`1` here means that there is one block of data to write; so `fwrite()` will write the whole data at once. `f` is the file you're writing to. And it returns the number of blocks written (so `1` on success and `0` on failure).

---

For completeness, I should note that's only one of the approaches to use of `fwrite()`. It may be a bit more semantic to use something like:

```
fwrite(test, sizeof(short), N, f)
```

but then the `fwrite()` may actually write only part of the data, and you will need to care about that. In other words, if it returned less than *N*, you'd have to retry writing the remaining part.

Answer (score 4):

Like this:

```
test2 = (char*)test;
```

`test[4000]` means the 4001<sup>st</sup> item of array `test`, not the array itself.

In general though, this is not a good idea. In the very least, your program won't be portable between big-endian and little-endian systems. Nevertheless, if you are coding for a specific microcontroller for example, it's ok.

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing is likely a bad idea, but...

```
test2 = (char*) test;
```